# Efficient search for an element other than the one used for ordering in std::set

Tags: performance, search, iterator, set

Consider the following set implementation. Here I have ordered the set based on fScore parameter. What should I do If I want to search for an element of particular 'id' in 'NodeData'.
I know I can use 'find' to search for any element of 'fScore' in the set with O(logn).
Is there any efficient way to search for 'id' (less time) than a linear search (implemented below)?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<set>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
struct NodeData{
        int id;
        int parent;
        double fScore, gScore, hScore;
        std::vector<double> nScores;

        NodeData(const int& idIn = 0,
                const int& parentIn = -1,
                const double& fIn = 1,
                const double& gIn = 1,
                const double& hIn = 1):id(idIn), parent(parentIn), 
                fScore(fIn), gScore(gIn), hScore(hIn)
        {
        }
bool operator<(const NodeData& rhs) const {
    return fScore < rhs.fScore;
}
};

class test
{
        public:
        std::set<NodeData> NodeList;

};

int main()
{
        test q;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        NodeData n1 = {i,1,i,1,1};
        q.NodeList.insert(n1);
    }
    std::set<NodeData>::iterator it;
    //search for node with fScore 1 - cost O(logn)
    it = q.NodeList.find(1);    
     if(it != q.NodeList.end()){
    std::cout<<"node with fScore 1 found. id = "<<it->id<<std::endl;
    }
    else{   
    std::cout<<"node not found = "<<std::endl;
    }
    //searching for id=3 - Linear search - cost O(n) 
    int searchId = 3;
    std::set<NodeData>::iterator it1 = q.NodeList.begin();
    while(it1 != q.NodeList.end())
    {
        if(it1->id == searchId)
        {
            std::cout <<"found node with id = "<<it1->id<<std::endl;    
        }
    it1++;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `set` changes often? If not - you could consider building an "index" - `unordered_map<>` of whatever field you need to the element of your set.

There is a cost of maintaining such "index", you should see if it overweights the faster search.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using this set for a priority queue. I can not afford to have another data structure since the set changes a lot during push and pop operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this without using different/additional data structures. If you're using C++ and you're OK with using a library, you can find this functionality in the [Boost multi-index containers library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Falk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64232638/213114), here's an example of how the thing could be done with Boost.MultiIndex:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71f8c540cf6fcbe2)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

struct NodeData{
    int id;
    int parent;
    double fScore, gScore, hScore;
    std::vector<double> nScores;

    NodeData(const int& idIn = 0,
             const int& parentIn = -1,
             const double& fIn = 1,
             const double& gIn = 1,
             const double& hIn = 1):id(idIn), parent(parentIn), 
             fScore(fIn), gScore(gIn), hScore(hIn)
    {
    }
    
    bool operator<(const NodeData& rhs) const {
        return fScore < rhs.fScore;
    }
};

class test
{
        public:
        typedef boost::multi_index_container<
            NodeData,
            boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
                boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
                    boost::multi_index::identity<NodeData>
                >,
                boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
                    boost::multi_index::member<NodeData, int, &NodeData::id>
                >
            >
        > NodeListType;
        NodeListType NodeList;

};

int main()
{
    test q;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        NodeData n1 = {i,1,double(i),1,1};
        q.NodeList.insert(n1);
    }
    test::NodeListType::iterator it;
    //search for node with fScore 1 - cost O(logn)
    it = q.NodeList.find(1);    
    if(it != q.NodeList.end()){
    std::cout<<"node with fScore 1 found. id = "<<it->id<<std::endl;
    }
    else{   
    std::cout<<"node not found = "<<std::endl;
    }
    //searching for id=3 on second index - cost O(logn) 
    int searchId = 3;
    test::NodeListType::nth_index<1>::type::iterator it1 = q.NodeList.get<1>().find(searchId);
    if(it1 != q.NodeList.get<1>().end()){
        std::cout <<"found node with id = "<<it1->id<<std::endl;    
    }   
}
```

If, instead of an ordered index, you use a hashed index for `NodeData::id`, lookup is constant (in average).